# How to make the output a percentage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code and output:

```
#Percentage of data with 95% or greated discount
print((df[df["itc_disc_95_itc_sku"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100, 'Percent of ITC Sku discounts were between 95 and 120')
print((df[df["itc_disc_95_disc_per_coupon"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100, 'Percent of Discounts per coupon were between 95 and 120')
print((df[df["itc_disc_95_disc_open_box"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100, 'Percent of Open Box Discounts were between 95 and 120')
print((df[df["itc_disc_95_disc_employee"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100, 'Percent of Employee discounts were between 95 and 120')
print((df[df["itc_disc_95_disc_overide"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100, 'Percent of Overide discounts were between 95 and 120')

12.0676663204247 Percent of ITC Sku discounts were between 95 and 120
8.827338637725374 Percent of Discounts per coupon were between 95 and 120
0.0855575236983875 Percent of Open Box Discounts were between 95 and 120
0.022239723285513567 Percent of Employee discounts were between 95 and 120
0.0 Percent of Overide discounts were between 95 and 120
```

I need to present the data in the notebook and want to format it so that it reads cleanly as a % and only two decimal places. Would want my desired output to look like:

```
12.07% Percent of ITC Sku discounts were between 95 and 120
8.83% Percent of Discounts per coupon were between 95 and 120
0.09% Percent of Open Box Discounts were between 95 and 120
0.02% Percent of Employee discounts were between 95 and 120
0.0% Percent of Overide discounts were between 95 and 120
```

Comment: And what did you do that caused an on topic issue to crop up?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Modern Pythons have three different methods of formatting numbers.  Surely you must have tried one of them.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this basic language feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  It seems that you haven't tried to look up Python output formatting.

Answer (score 1):

An f-string with `%`? Then you don't need the `* 100`.

```
>>> x = 0.120676663204247
>>> f'{x:.2%} of all questions are not completely terrible'
'12.07% of all questions are not completely terrible'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just use f-strings, specifying .2f if you want two decimals:

```
print(f'{(df[df["itc_disc_95_itc_sku"] == True].shape[0] /df.shape[0])*100:.2f}%, Percent of ITC Sku discounts were between 95 and 120')
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this ?

```
num1 = ...
percentage = '{0.2%}'.format(num1)
print(percentage)
```

2 is the number of decimal places that you need, you can change it if you want